# I can no longer build my Unity project on iOS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development, il2cpp

I've been facing a problem in Unity for days.
Indeed, everything goes well when I build the project on Android, however, on iOS it is impossible to build (problem that I did not have before).

I'm using this version of Unity: 2022.3.2

The first error I get in the console: /Applications/2022.3.2f1/Unity.app/Contents/il2cpp/build/deploy/il2cpp --convert-to-cpp

The second error:
BuildFailedException: Player build failed: /Applications/2022.3.2f1/Unity.app/Contents/il2cpp/build/deploy/il2cpp --convert-to-cpp

[image: The errors in question]

Any help will be appreciated, thank you in advance.

I removed two sdk's to see if the problem was coming from there, but nothing changed.

Comment: What changed since the last time you were able to build it? If you have source control this is pretty easy to determine.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank you for the answer. Last time I was able to build the project on iOS because I was using an older version of Unity (2020.3.19 LTS). And what do you mean by source control? Thank you.